# How to resolve ambiguity error in Rails? Undefined method '_index_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails convention urges everyone to name models, controllers and other things the way they are named in real life.

I've run into a problem, where my form can't recognize the right form of instance variable.

I have **Fish** model and corresponding **fish** controller.

```
class FishController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @fish = Fish.new
  end
end
```

Then when I get on my form, I get the error.

```
<%= form_for @fish do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :type %>
  <%= f.text_field :type, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

I'm using **Rails 4.2.5**.

Here's my routes.rb.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'fish#index'

  get 'fish' => 'fish#index'
  post 'fish' => 'fish#index'
end
```

How can I resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RoR version do you use, 3 or 4? What is `Fish`? ActiveRecord model? Something else? Have you defined resource in your routes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for` when given the resource tries to build the name of default url_helper which would be created if you go with a rails way and add resource for that model in your routes. Since `fish` plural is still `fish`, the name of the helper is `fish_index_path`.

Obviously, this is only the convention, and all that stuff can be easily changed. You have couple of options.

First is to add `url` option to your `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for @fish, url: '/fish' do |f| %>
```

this might be painful when you decide later to change your routes, as it is easy to forget.

Other option is to name your route:

```
get 'fish' => 'fish#index', as: :fish_index
```

Another is to follow the convention and create a resource:

```
 resources :fish, only: [:index, :create]
```

UPDATE:

This is a big no-no to handle two different verbs with the same action. There are very rare cases when that makes sense.

Comment: I use two verbs within the same action because I want to have both table with records(index) and creation form(create) on the same page.

Comment: @BillyLogan - Then send form to create action and redirect user back to index. The problem with your current approach is that when user refreshes the page after form submition, it would create a new  duplicate record in the database.

Comment: @BillyLogan - The rule thumb I use - POST actions should pretty much always redirect. The only case when this does not apply is when form submition does not store anything in the database (like advanced search form which is too big to be submitted through GET method). GET actions should never make db saves - and there are no exceptions here as this is a serious security gap.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the conventional actions for your use case. Creating a new object should happen in the `create` action of the controller, e.g.

```
def create
  @fish = Fish.create(fish_params)
  redirect_to index_path
end
```